# Import and cloning from Git to android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, google-glass

I am new in using android studio I an currently trying to build the interface between the Google Glass and computer, for that i first need to debug my glass using some sample examples from Git but i am not able to clone those examples to android studio . It says "Clone Failed" "Failed to start Git process"

Comment: What are the steps you did that gave these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to make comments, so I'll try to provide you an answer without knowing the specifics of your setup. If this answer is misleading, please comment below and I'll try to improve it.

First make sure you have the git executable installed. Then go to the menu `File->Settings`. Under the section `Version Control->Git`, fill in the `Path to Git Executable` field. The exact path will depend on your system and version of git installed.

Comment: Yeah, that was perfect it works fine now ,thank you :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Would you mind marking this answer as accepted, as that counts towards my reputation. Thanks.